# How to switch between 2 LEDs using a powered momentary DPDTswitch

Tags: led, switches, dpdt

[Problem http://www.webamplayer.com/dpdt.jpg](http://www.webamplayer.com/dpdt.jpg)

I need a visual indication which way the DPDT has been thrown. Should I use a relay?

Comment: I do not understand: do you want something like: "you temporarily put the DPDT in position A, led A goes on and stays on, same for B" or "you temporarily put the DPDT in position A, led A blinks, same for B". If the behaviour is the first one, when should the leds turn off?

Comment: When the Momentary DPDT is thrown to A it turns on the power for a fraction of second and comes back to off position. This makes the mechanical part connected with a solenoid coil go in one direction. When the DPDT is thrown to B again the same thing happens but the mechanical part goes in the reverse direction. I need a LED 1 to glow constantly when thrown to A. When thrown to B the LED 1 will go off and LED 2 will start glowing.

Comment: @vladimir its a momentary dpdt, connected to two latching solenoids, from what I understand. So OP needs a matching Latching circuit for two leds.

Comment: Probably an active high latch.

Answer (score 1):

Use any two different color LEDS reversed in parallel with a single R to limit current like 1k and connect across switch (to mechanical device).

Do you have +7 or -7V to load or +- V where V = 5 to 12?  Latter I guess.

LEDs will be selected with polarity and protect themselves from excess reverse voltage .

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The actual load voltage is just 5v. 12v regulated by a 7805 regulator.What are the 2 resistors at the top right end?

Comment: Also I cannot understand the switch connection. Currently my supply is at the centre 2 poles of the DPDT.

Comment: Pullup resistors eg 10k are essential. Relay follows your layout , with output to your bipolar latching  load. Logic responds to whichever output is at 0V immediately and latches. Disregard my12V and I'll disregard yours.  +5V make sure you have clamp protection diode on each output to 5V on switch to protect CMOS which has internal diodes but only rated for 15mA.